# where is the presale.wallet available to import?

Tags: presale

I am very new to ethereum community, just started setting up ethereum in my machine hoping to mine some ether.

I have downloaded and run geth.exe, created a new account.

My next step according to link i am following is importing a presale.wallet file

> https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts

My question is how do i do that? where can i find it?

I tried just giving some path hoping it will download it but got the following error

> Fatal: Could not read wallet file: read
>   C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum: The handle is invalid.

please help me solve this. And any links or tips on how to effectively mine will be helpfull.

Thanks in advance,
Mahesh

Comment: Did you buy/were you given any ether in the presale? If not, then you won't have a presale wallet. That part of the instructions is for people who do.

Comment: No i did not buy any ether. I was assuming that the mined ether will be getting added to this wallet.Now I got calrified. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the next step, this operation is reserved to those whom bought ether during the presale. 
since you are starting mining you don't have such wallet.